# how to define dependencies correctly in nuspec

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I created a library for Xamarin forms and I want to publish it as Nuget package. There are several dependencies and in nuspec I used the following notation

```
 <dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="netstandard1.1">
    <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" />
    <dependency id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.5.0.91635" />
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
  </group>
  <group targetFramework="MonoAndroid">
    <dependency id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" version="42.1021.1" />
    <dependency id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places" version="42.1021.1" />
    <dependency id="Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils" version="0.5.0" />
    <dependency id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.5.0.91635" />
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

Now when I reference the nuget package in a project that uses the latest Xamarin Google libraries, I get an error

```
Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location 42.1021.1 requires Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1021.1) but version Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 71.1620.0 was resolved.
```

Referencing the [Nuget Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/concepts/package-versioning) my notation sais: accept all versions greater than or equal to 42.1021.1. So what's the correct notation to include 42.1021.1 and 71.1620.0 as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding square brackets to the version to fully restrict the version you are using.

```xml
<!-- Accept only version 6.1. -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="[6.1]" />

<!-- Accepts any 6.x.y version. -->
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="[6,7)" />
```

For more documentation please look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#Constraining_Upgrades_To_Allowed_Versions